# How to pass data or communicate between C# and Javascript in Windows Phone 8.1 App

Tags: javascript, c#, windows-phone-8, webview

In a Windows Phone 8.1 app I'm running `javascript` code in a `webview` which needs to call a `C#` method and the `C#` method returns some `string` data. I need this `string` data in the javascript code from where the `C#` method was called previously. How can I do this data passing operation in Windows Phone 8.1 app?

To be more specific, I've trying to use somewhat following snippet in javascript:

```
var jsVariable = ClassName.MethodName(params);
```

`ClassName` is a class in `C#` and  `MethodName(params)` is a method of the class.

As far I know, I can call the `C#` method with `window.external.notify()` from the javascript side, but how can I receive the data sent by the `C#` method that is just called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `C#` you can't directly access the methods of an object this way. But you can still call and get data returned from the `c#` methods by calling `InvokeScriptAsync()` method of `WebView` class.

From the `javascript` code call `window.external.notify(params)` with `params` as which method to be called, parse this `params` in the `c#` code and execute the method there, send the result back to the `javascript` by calling `WebViewName.invokeScriptAsync()`.

You may
[find more here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/08f6d8a8-7316-4ae3-a43e-11959aea2e79/the-best-way-to-pass-data-between-c-and-js).